# what is the right way to git stash pop?

Tags: git, git-stash

I `git stash` my changes, then I pick the updates up using `git stash pop`, but the `gitk` still shows the stashed version, what is the right way to pick up the updates?

Comment: Seems ok, did you reload the gitk view ? It caches the commit tree before displaying, and thus the stash is visible.

Comment: Reload gitk's view with `shift-f5` to reread all refs.

Comment: yes, I reloaded it, but it still shows the stashed version

Answer (score 0):

Check your stash:

```
git stash show -p
```

Pretty sure you're fine, but worth a check. As long as you do it on the same branch it's no problem.